# Filter array by matching id properties

Tags: arrays, swift

I feel like this has to be answered some where, but I have been searching for a few days with no luck. I have an example below. I have an array of users and I need to filter them down to the ones that have a matching ID property, I know the code below doesn't compile.. would be very grateful for any help with this.

```
    struct User {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

let userArray = [
    User(id: 1, name: "A"),
    User(id: 2, name: "B"),
    User(id: 1, name: "C"),
    User(id: 3, name: "D"),
]


let newArray = userArray.filter({ $0.id == $1.id })


//  This is what i want to achieve 
// newArray = [User(id: 1, name: "A"),  User(id: 1, name: "C")]
```

> In the actual project, the id is dynamically returned. So I just need to be able to check for what is matching, without knowing what the id will actually be.

Comment: The answer from lucas sort of answers your question, but that is because your question is unclear.  What is your aim?  Is it to isolate any users that have the same id?  if so, what happens if you have two users with id == 1 and three with id == 2?  How do you want to handle this?

Comment: @flanker thank you, ok well it is being returned in a collection view cell, so each time it cycles through should create a different instance for each cell.  I need to populate an array for each matching id on user, and then be able to index individual through them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach won't work as filter only takes one dynamic parameter and only processes one item at a time.  Therefore it can't match two separate array entries.

You example also doesn't specify how you want to handle the situation where you have multiples of different User.id.  This answer assumes you want to be able to separate them into separate arrays.

`Dictionary` has a handy initialiser that will do the bulk of the work for you and group on a defined property. Grouping on `id` will give you a dictionary where the key is the `id` and the values an array of matching `User` records.  You can then filter the dictionary to get a dictionary where there are multiple users for any `id`.

```
let multiples = Dictionary(grouping: userArray, by: \.id).filter{$0.value.count > 1}
```

Using your data you will end up with a dictionary of:

```
[1: [User(id: 1, name: "A"), User(id: 1, name: "C")] ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally makes since, I had a feeling filter wasn't correct, but I wasn't sure what else would achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in filter does not compare to a given id value. Below is one added called, which I call matchingId:

```
struct User {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
}

let userArray = [
  User(id: 1, name: "A"),
  User(id: 2, name: "B"),
  User(id: 1, name: "C"),
  User(id: 3, name: "D"),
]

let matchingId = 1   // or: let matchingId = someFunctionCallReturningAnId()

let result = userArray.filter { $0.id == matchingId }

print(result)
```

Comment: but the id in the real world project is dynamic, I just need to check if there the same?

Comment: Then replace _1_ in _let matchingId = 1_ with a function call. The important thing is, that in your code you do not compare against anything. $1 in your code is not even valid, as the _filter_ closure only has one argument (called $0) and that is the current item of the array.

Comment: ok, can you elaborate with an example on what the function would do ?

Comment: You say, that this value you want to filter by (which I call matchingId) is dynamic. I do not know where this comes from, you do. It does not have to be a function call, it can be anything which can be assigned to matchingId and is an Int.